# GO does not exist when logged in as sudo, does when logged in as user

Tags: go, installation, failed-installation, ubuntu-17.10

The title is the problem - here is a brief explanation as to how I got here as I imagine that may help with sleuthing.

I installed go, and everything was fine. I ran `build essential golang` command on Ubuntu, and all of a sudden my go version was out of sync with my `/usr/local/go/src/VERSION` file.

I deleted my go files at `/usr/local/go/`, as well as the go and the go-1.8 folders in `/usr/bin/`. I then reinstalled go at `/usr/local/go`

Now, when I run `go env` as a user, the output looks correct. However (the title), when I am `sudo`, no go commands are recognized and I get the following message: The program 'go' can be found in the following packages:
 * golang-go
 * gccgo-go

As a user, some of my go env output is:

```
GOPATH="/home/{me}/go"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
```

As a user, my `echo $PATH` is :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/{me}/go/bin
```

My `~/.profile` includes:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

Help, please? : )

Comment: This question directly involves a tool used primarily for programming, the Go programming language compiler and tools. It's on-topic.

Comment: `sudo su - root` then `Go` dissappears from my system too..Maybe the PATH is not set for `root`

Answer (score 1):

You should ask in another community, like: [unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

But, the problem is that when you log as root, the PATH variable is set as configured for root user. you have to configure the PATH environment variable of root user, or run su/sudo as following:

```
su --preserve-environment -
sudo --preserve-env bash
```